# How do I create a Fargate Service without load balancer from AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

**The Context:** I am trying to create a Fargate service using aws cdk. I do not require any load balancer in the Fargate service.

**The Problem:** While aws console allows creation of service without any load balancer like seen in the picture below, I cannot find any **ecsPatterns** to achieve the same through the **cdk**. The ecs patterns create the load balancer automatically if not specified.

How do I create a fargate service without load balancer from cdk ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.FargateService.html) construct.